# Is Clash cross platform multiplayer without account transfer?

Tags: clash-of-clans, ios, android

If a Clash of Clans account is created on an android phone and never account transferred to an iDevice, when in global chat and attack searching will it only find android device bases or iDevice bases too?

Same in reverse If a Clash of Clans account is created on an iDevice and never account transferred to an android phone, when in global chat and attack searching will it only find iDevice bases or android bases too?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an official source, but I have played this game for over a year and can say that it is a cross platform game. My brother who uses android and I who use iOS can both find people who use the other device in both global chat and while attacking.

Best source I can find currently is here- http://www.thoughtworthy.info/BlogPost/58/A-Free-Mobile-Multiplayer-Game-Clash-of-Clans

Comment: Have you ever transferred your account from an iDevice to the android or vice versa?

Comment: @Foxhound no I have not. I've always been on an iOS device and he has always been on an android. Both devices will connect to the same server. As someone who uses mobile apps on a regular basis and developes them, I can tell you this is very common among apps.

Comment: No, as a developer and mobile game enthusiast it is not popular.

Answer (score 1):

All towns are on the **same server** and so CoC doesn't make any difference if you play on Android or on iOS or on both of them in a mess.

[Also found this post on the official forum](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/157780-Play-together).

I for myself can also confirm this as I have played it with many iPhone users (as Android User) together in a clan. Some have also switched their OS but not faced any problems.

Comment: You say you played with many iPhone users, so I am assuming you have an Android device? It is not fully clear from your answer though.

Comment: @Daniel true, I edited it, however the next sentence should make it more evident since some switched and in this regard my own OS is trivial